# IE doesn't like header html or css?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm just trying to lay out a simple wireframe, and IE isn't liking my code. I've been playing around a lot today with my header trying to get it right, and I am not sure what it's nt liking, it validates fine. It's just displaying my nav items, but will not follow the links, and my image doesnt show and just displays the alt tag. Chrome and Firefox display fine. Any ideas? Here is my header code, and my css:

**HTML**:

```
<header>
        <div id="header-container">

            <!-- Hidden heading for outline -->
            <h1>Wordsmithery - Home</h1>

            <a href="index.html"> <img src="Images/header-logo.jpg" alt="wordsmithery-logo" width="250" height="50"/> </a>

            <nav>
                <!-- Hidden nav heading for outline -->
                <h2>Navigation</h2>
                <ol>
                    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>    
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tips.html">Tips</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a></li>
                 </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="clearFix"></div>
    </header>
```

**CSS**:

```
/* Header */
header{
height: 60px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #D1D1D1;
margin: 0px;
border-bottom: 5px solid #ffffff;
position: fixed;
z-index: 5;
}
#header-container{
width:940px;
height: 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
header img{
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 5px;
float:left;
}
header h1{
display: none;
}

/* Navigation */
nav{    
float:left;
margin-top: 30px;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 18px;
color: black;
font-weight: 300;
}
nav h2{
display: none;
}
nav li{
display: inline;
padding-left: 10px;
}
nav li:last-child{
margin-left: 150px;
font-size:  14px;
}

nav ol {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

nav a {text-decoration: none; padding: 5px;}

.clearFix {clear: both;}

a:link {color:#999999;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color: inherit;}
a:hover {color:#ffffff;
    o-transition:color .4s ease-out;
    ms-transition:color .4s ease-out;
    moz-transition:color .4s ease-out;
    webkit-transition:color .4s ease-out;
/* ...and now override with proper CSS property */
    transition:color .4s ease-out;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#FFFFFF;}  /* selected link */
```

Comment: Add modernizr.js - your IE does not know what <header> is.

Comment: Try adding a reference to HTML5shiv or shim.

Comment: What is the doctype? Is there one? (is IE running in Quirks or Standards mode?)

Comment: Too much information missing. For example, does the page work on IE if you switch off CSS support or omit the CSS code? This would tell you whether the problem is in styling or elsewhere.

Comment: Okay, this just got weird. for some reason it's just the index.html file that's having issues. Other pages with exactly the same code in the header function completely fine, but my index page navigation does not display. I even copy pasted a working page, and for some reason it just won't work with index.html!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this into your 'head' tag!

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I did add the shiv, but no luck. Still giving me issues! It's so weird that all my other pages work fine and index.html doesn't even if it's copy pasted from another page that works somewhere else.